# SQL Joining on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Ok, here was my original question;

Table one contains

```
ID|Name  
1  Mary  
2  John
```

Table two contains

```
ID|Color  
1  Red  
1  Blue
2  Blue  
2  Green  
2  Black
```

I want to end up with is

```
ID|Name|Red|Blue|Green|Black  
1  Mary Y   Y  
2  John     Y     Y     Y
```

It seems that because there are 11 unique values for color and 1000's upon 1000's of records in table one that there is no 'good' way to do this. So, two other questions.

Is there an efficient way to query to get this result? I can then create a crosstab in my application to get the desired result.

```
ID|Name|Color  
1  Mary  Red  
1  Mary  Blue  
2  John  Blue  
2  John  Green  
2  John  Black
```

If I wanted to limit the number of records returned how could I do a query to do something like this?

```
Where ((color='blue') AND (color<>'red' OR color<>'green'))
```

So using the above example I would then get back

```
ID|Name|Color  
1  Mary  Blue  
2  John  Blue  
2  John  Black
```

I connect to Visual FoxPro tables via ADODB to use SQL. Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? This is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your prior question, and querying against a VFP table, you could get your results by
the following VFP qualified query... cross-tab complete

```
select
      N.ID,
      N.Name,
      MAX( IIF( C.Color = "Red", "Y", " " )) Red,
      MAX( IIF( C.Color = "Blue", "Y", " " )) Blue,
      MAX( IIF( C.Color = "Green", "Y", " " )) Green,
      MAX( IIF( C.Color = "Black", "Y", " " )) Black
   FROM
      C_Names N,
      Colors C
   WHERE
      N.ID = C.ID
   GROUP BY 
      N.ID,
      N.Name
```

Then, as you have other "colors", just copy the MAX( IIF()) for that respective color and have the column as the result column name... follow the pattern.  Only issue is if you have different case-sensitve spelling of the colors, then you may need to UPPER( C.Color ) = "RED" (or similar for other colors)

Comment: Thanks. That does it without any noticeable increase in processing time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to make a crosstab query. You could try to use the crosstab query wizard:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979431%28VS.71%29.aspx